# Como modificar la visualizacion del campo fecha a String POSTGRESQL

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

Estoy tratando de realizar un gráfico y estoy teniendo un problema con la visualización de las fechas, en la BD cree una columna fecha que es tipo Date y me muestra la fecha de la siguiente forma: 01/08/2019 pero lo que necesito es que se visualice de la siguiente forma Agosto-2019 o similar y quería hacerlo mediante una consulta, me podrían ayudar

Datos en mi Tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gráfico de Metabase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces lo que quiero es mediante la consulta modificar la visualizacion de la fecha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacer algo como esto. (colocandole todos los meses)

```
select 
fecha,
case 
    when trim(to_char(fecha, 'MONTH')) = 'JANUARY' then 'Enero'
    when trim(to_char(fecha, 'MONTH')) = 'FEBRUARY' then 'Febrero'
    when trim(to_char(fecha, 'MONTH')) = 'JUNE' then 'Junio'
    -- hacer lo mismo con todos los meses
end || to_char(fecha, '-YYYY') as fechaformateada
from tutabla;
```

obtendras una respuesta como esta:

```
fecha                 | fechaformateada
18.06.2020 03:13:01   | Junio-2020
```

Aqui alguien posteo algo parecido y tambien se ve como cambiar los dias de la semana: [postgresql-date-format-and-local-language-output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43895101/11282862)

La [documentacion oficial de postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-formatting.html) tambien te será de utilidad